# Is there any flexlm licensing api to detect machine UUID

Tags: flexlm

Is there any flexlm licensing api to detect machine UUID. I am using flexlm version 11.13.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

`FlexNet` Publisher (formerly FlexLM) supports some callout variations using `vendor-defined, host-ids and checkout/callback` functions, including `VM_UUID`. For physical machines, its often recommended using multiple identifiers.